# Exception when adding element to ArrayList while iterate

Tags: collections

I am trying to add an String object into `ArrayList<String>` while iterating it. then i have a Exception like :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at com.alonegk.corejava.collections.list.ArrayListDemo.main(ArrayListDemo.java:19)
```

the piece of code as -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> al =new ArrayList<String>();

    al.add("str1");
    al.add("str2");

    Iterator<String> it = al.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
        al.add("gkgk");

    }
```

there is no synchronization here. i need to know the cause of this exception ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999388/why-iterator-throws-concurrentmodificationexception-on-add)  for `ConcurrentModificationException`.Try using `ListIterator<String>` if you want to add new value in the iterator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<String> al =new ArrayList<String>();

al.add("str1");
al.add("str2");

ListIterator<String> it = al.listIterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.add("gkgk");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ConcurrentModificationException is used to fail-fast when something we are iterating and modifying at the same time

we can do the modification by using iterator directly as

```
 for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Integer integer = iterator.next();
    if(integer == 2) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```